# How to use azure storage with max throughput

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage

I have a file storage with a really big amount of files. When I run scripts for it (for example script for counting the files in every nested directory) it could take more that 12h.

I use nodejs and and `for(dir of dirs) {}` so, it checks every directory sequentially.
When I change it to await `Promise.all(dirs.map(async dir => {}))` I have an error "Server is busy".

Does anybody have a good solution? Or maybe a good library-wrapper for azure-storage?

**UPDATE:**

What I started to do:

```
async listFilesAndDirectories(directory) {
    while (this.isSleep) {
      await sleep(50)
    }
    while (this.counter > 50) {
      this.isSleep = true
      await sleep(1000)
      this.isSleep = false
      this.counter = 0
    }
    this.counter++
    const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.fileService.listFilesAndDirectoriesSegmented(
        this.shareName,
        directory,
        CURRENT_TOKEN,
        function(error, result, response) {
          if (!error) {
            resolve(result)
          } else {
            reject(error)
          }
        }
      )
    })
    const result = await p
    return result.entries
  }
```

But 50 requests is too few. In Doc Microsoft says that their throughput is 1000 or 10000 op/sec.

Comment: The REST API will likely be a lot faster for such operations. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-directories-and-files or the SDK for it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/storage-file-share-readme?view=azure-node-latest

Comment: yes, I use it. But it doesn't prevent me of "server is busy" error. I tried to run it concurrently and add a wrapper for sdk method, but anyway it looks strange: my max limit is about 50 files per sec, but in doc they say that throughput is 1000 or 10000 op/sec. + this method anyway sometimes throw an error. Check the question please, I updated it